# Forward declaring enum class inside template parameter?

Tags: c++

I want to forward declare a strongly typed enum (enum class) inside a template parameter. It doesn't work if it's already defined, because a strongly typed enum can't be referenced by "enum class".

I want to do this because File 2 might not know the enum definition. How do I fix this?

Compiles:

```
// File 1
template<typename TEnum>
class TSomeClass
{
    int m_someMember;
};

// File 2
struct MyStruct
{
    TSomeClass<enum class MyEnum : int> someClassInstance;
};

enum class MyEnum : int
{
    someIdentifier
};
```

Doesn't compile:

```
// File 1
template<typename TEnum>
class TSomeClass
{
    int m_someMember;
};

enum class MyEnum : int
{
    someIdentifier
};

// File 2
struct MyStruct
{
    TSomeClass<enum class MyEnum : int> someClassInstance;
                  //^ error: "reference to scoped enumeration must use 'enum' not 'enum class'"
};
```

Doesn't compile either:

```
// File 1
template<typename TEnum>
class TSomeClass
{
    int m_someMember;
};

// File 2
struct MyStruct
{
    TSomeClass<enum MyEnum : int> someClassInstance;
};

enum class MyEnum : int
         //^ error: "enumeration previously declared as unscoped"
{
    someIdentifier
};
```

As an additional note, it seems to work with Visual Studio 2015.
However, Clang 4.0.0 gives me "reference to scoped enumeration must use 'enum' not 'enum class'"

Edit: I'm searching for an alternative to the usual forward declaration of enums (which would be outside the template parameter).
Forward declaration for structs/classes work fine inside template parameters, why don't they work for "enum class"?

Comment: Why do it inside a template parameter?!

Comment: See my reply to Jarod42 and my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may forward declaration of enum first:

```
enum class MyEnum : int;

struct MyStruct
{
    TSomeClass<MyEnum> someClassInstance;
};
```

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to specify but these enums and structs are auto generated by a tool and there are lots of them, so the easiest way is to forward declare them in the template parameter instead. I'm searching for an alternative of what you're proposing.